# What metadata is passed when a mobile web browser launches a native iOS app using a custom URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mobile, metadata

I am curious as to what metadata is passed when Safari launches a native iOS app using a custom URL.

For example: If an iOS user clicks on a Google Maps custom URL that launches the Google maps app, what metadata (or any data for that matter) does the Google Maps app receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I get what you're asking, but basically, the app receive the whole URL. It is to the website owner's discretion to include any data he likes in it.

For example if I register the URL scheme `mygreatapp://` [in my app's `.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW20), and I add a link `mygreatapp://cakes?flavor=chocolate` to my website, when an user tap the link, iOS will launch my app (provided the user has installed it), and message my `UIApplicationDelegate` with:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

[Method documentation on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW26).

The `url` argument will then contain the full URL I put on my website in the form of an `NSURL` object, from which I can extract the different parts (ie. `cakes` and `{flavor: chocolate}`).

In addition to the URL, the app will also be passed the bundle id of the source app the user is coming from in the argument `sourceApplication`. In the case of an URL opened from Safari, the `sourceApplication` value is `com.apple.mobilesafari`.

The `annotation` argument is used when your app is opened from another app implementing an [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDocumentInteractionController/annotation). I'm not too experienced with this, so you might want to check out [this tutorial](http://easyplace.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-pass-a-document-from-one-app-to-another/) for more infos.

To answer your question more specifically, when opening Google Maps, [you can add multiple parameters to the URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) depending on what you want to display. eg.

```
comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic
```

And [here's a long list of the URL schemes of famous apps](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Guillaume! That is exactly what I was wondering. Specifically, would Safari (or any other web browser) ever be able to pass the referring URL to the new app? For example, if the custom URL ``mygreatapp://cakes?flavor=chocolate`` was tapped on from the website ``http://www.mygreatappwebsite.com``, would the web browser ever be able to send that refrring URL (``http://www.mygreatappwebsite.com``) to the app that it launches (``mygreatapp://``)?

Comment: Yes, by adding the current page URL to the link. For example in PHP you could do something like : `<a href="mygreatapp://cakes?favor=chocolate&referer=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>"` (this is an example, you should probably escape the value for security reasons, not add php code in your templates, etc.).

Comment: Ok great. Just so I'm clear, by default there is no way for the referring URL to be passed from the web browser app (``Safari, Chrome, etc``) to the app that is launched by the custom URL (``mygreatapp://cakes?flavor=chocolate``)?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.